# Recommendations on where to learn and practice linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming, linear-algebra

[CLOSED] Thanks!
I am studying Linear Programming in college but I am facing some difficulties to assimilate some concepts.

So do you have any recommendations of materials to learn or practice Linear Programming?

Thanks

Comment: Chapter 29 of [CLRS](https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation!